# Representing volumes using isosurfaces

Tags: python, 3d, vtk, mayavi

I would like to represent a bunch of particles (~100k grains), for which I have the position (including rotation) and a discretized level set function (i.e. the signed distance of every voxel from surface). Due to the large sample, I'm searching for eficient solutions to visualize it.

I first went for vtk, using its python interface, but I'm not really sure if it's the best (and simplest) way to do it since, as far as I know, there is no direct implementation for getting an isosurface from a 3D data set. In the beginning I was thinking usind marching cubes, but then I still would have to use a threshold or to interpolate in order to get the voxels that are on the surface and label them in order to be used by the marching cubes.

Now I found mayavi which has a python function

```
mlab.pipeline.iso_surface()
```

I however did not find much documentation on it and was wondering how it behaves in terms of performance.

Does someone have experience with this kind of tools? Which would be the best solution (in terms of efficiency and, secondly, in terms of simplicity - I do not know the vtk library, but if there is a huge difference in performance I can dig into it, also without python interface).